# JavaScript: Tips on how to use onblur to get info from another server and auto populate other textbox entries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a web page using primarily HTML, CSS and JavaScript (I'm fairly new to making websites, so these are the only three I am fairly decent with). This web page will be a form that will interface with an enterprise software (BMC Remedy ITSM) that will enforce validation and make all of our tickets precise when submitted.

One of the few static textboxes on the web page will be an ID number field, a full-name field and a phone-number field.

My goal is to have the user put in their ID number, and have this ID number communicate with the enterprise software, look up the ID number, and auto-populate the full name and phone number from the ID number given.

I want this to be a lostfocus event on the ID number textbox, so therefore I guess it would be under onblur for JavaScript.

Can someone chime in and give me some pointers on how I would achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the data returned from the other server? json?

Comment: It's being returned via XML.

Answer (score 0):

A quick example of using the blur event is below in pure JavaScript. Top example shows JSON return and bottom example shows XML.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9dpxmpru/2/

HTML:

```
<input id="empid" type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" />
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" />
<input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" />
```

JS:

```
var empid = document.getElementById('empid');
empid.addEventListener('blur',
    function (event) {
        var idVal = this.value;
        // make some ajax call
        // perhaps it returns this
        var response = {
            name: "John Doe",
            phone: "555-5555"
        };
        var name = document.getElementById('name');
        var phone = document.getElementById('phone');
        name.value = response.name;
        phone.value = response.phone;
    }, true
);
```

As for the ajax call you can do something like this:

```
// Make Ajax Call
var requestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
requestObject.open('POST', 'someurl', true);
requestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
// XML: requestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
requestObject.onload = function () {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        // Success!
    }
    else {
        // Handle some server error
    }
};
requestObject.onerror = function () {
    // Handle some server error
};
requestObject.send(JSON.stringify('idValueFromField'));
```

This is of course very rough but the general idea.

Here is fiddle parsing xml: http://jsfiddle.net/9dpxmpru/4/

```
var empid = document.getElementById('empid');
empid.addEventListener('blur',
    function (event) {
        var idVal = this.value;
        // make some ajax call
        // perhaps it returns this
        var response = "<response><name>John Doe</name><phone>555-5555</phone></response>";
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/xml');
        var name = document.getElementById('name');
        var phone = document.getElementById('phone');
        name.value = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        phone.value = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('phone')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }, true
);
```

jQuery Examples:

```
$("#empid").on("focusout",
    function (event) {
        var idVal = $(this).val();
        // make some ajax call
        // perhaps it returns this
        var response = {
            name: "John Doe",
            phone: "555-5555"
        };
        $("#name").val(response.name);
        $("#phone").val(response.phone);
    }
);
```

jQuery Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "someurl",
    dataType: 'json',
    // XML: dataType: 'xml',
    data: {
        empid: idVal
    }
}).done(
    function (msg) {
        // success!
    }
);
```

jQuery XML example:

```
$("#empid").on("focusout",
    function (event) {
        var idVal = $(this).val();
        // make some ajax call
        // perhaps it returns this
        var response = "<response><name>John Doe</name><phone>555-5555</phone></response>";
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response),
        var xml = $(xmlDoc),
        $("#name").val(xml.find("name").text());
        $("#phone").val(xml.find("phone").text());
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as your idea goes, you're on the right track. But since you said you're newer to web development, I'll explain more. You're going to have a text input that listens for a blur. The blur event will then send an XMLHttpRequest to your ITSM software, supplying a response handler that will execute as soon as the request completes.

If you haven't looked into it yet, and if you have the option, I would suggest jQuery, because it provides traversal functionality for HTML that also [mostly] works on XML. It'll also make your calls a bit easier.

HTML:

```
<input id="employeeId" type="text" placeholder="Employee ID">
<input id="fullName" type="text">
<input id="phone" type="text">
```

Assuming your XML is something like this:

```
<lotsOfResponseParentNodes>
      <person>
          <fullName>John Doe</fullName>
          <phoneNumber>5555551212</phoneNumber>
      </person>
</lotsOfResponseParentNodes>
```

JavaScript (place at bottom of body):

```
function setFieldVals(fullName, phoneNumber) {
  $("#phone").val(phoneNumber);
  $("#fullName").val(fullName);
}

$("#employeeId").blur(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",    //or GET, depending on your api spec
    url: ENDPOINT_URI,  //Again, depending on your software
    data: {employeeId: $(e.target).val()}
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      setFieldVals($(xml).find("fullName").text(), $(xml).find("phoneNumber").text());
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("An error happened.");
    }
  });
});
```

What's key here is how you're parsing your XML. In the XML example I have above, find("nodeName") works. But if the XML were, say, `<person phone="xxx">` then you'd have to `$(xml).find('person').attr('phone')` instead.